# HTML2PDF - add more than one page

Tags: php, pdf, html2pdf

I am  using HTML2PDF converter in PHP to generate PDF.

My html seems to be big so that it could not fit in single page.

I am getting following error when I tried to generate pdf..

'the contents of a TD tag does not fit on a single page'

could not find proper solution yet. Any idea please.

This is my code at end to generate pdf.

```
require_once("../html2pdf_new/html2pdf.class.php");

try
{
    $html2pdf = new HTML2PDF('P','A4','fr');
    $html2pdf->pdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
    $html2pdf->WriteHTML($content);
    $html2pdf->Output('exemple.pdf');
}

catch(HTML2PDF_exception $e) {
    echo $e;
    exit;
}
```

`$content` contains all html.

Comment: Perhaps try using divs instead of a table if that's an option?

Comment: No sir, i need to use table structure only.

Comment: I don't believe there is a direct workaround available to you then, other than breaking your content down into smaller chunks

Comment: sorry i didn't get you. can u please explain

Comment: Finally I used mpdf and got my result

Comment: @Shri I have the same issue, can you please write how you got it sorted and what is mpdf? Thanks.

Comment: @NaguibIhab take a look about mpdf here http://bit.ly/1lAqmT2 . It provides external css facility and some other good parameters for its object which helped me.

Answer (score 12):

You can set `setTestTdInOnePage` as false to overcome this error.

```
 $html2pdf = new HTML2PDF('P', 'A4', 'en');

 $html2pdf->setTestTdInOnePage(false);
```

Answer (score 3):

If this problem still exists: I fixed it with the method

`HTML2PDF::setTestTdInOnePage(false)`

This setting of value works. In the html2pdf main class file we have a method setTestTdInOnePage which does the rendering of td within a single page if set to true. As it is always true we have this exception thrown as our td data exceeds more than one page. So to avoid it we can set it to false to pass the check.

Answer (score 0):

if we have nested tables, it breaks for multiple pages.

Try to avoid nested tables.

It works.

found at [Forum](http://www.yaronet.com/en/posts.php?s=134980)

Answer (score -3):

Find this 'throw new HTML2PDF_exception(7);' in html2pdf.class.php and disable it. 
Like this:

```
   if ($this->_testTdInOnepage && $this->_subHtml->pdf->getPage()>1) {
       //throw new HTML2PDF_exception(7);
   }
```

Comment: Shri asked for "proper solution".
Try to comment the Exception only and look at the result, you will see this is no proper solution at all.